# Calling JavaScript function from C# UserControl

Tags: c#, javascript

I have developed a user control using C# and embedded it in a lotus domino web page by using below code:

```
<OBJECT id="myUserControl" name="myUserControl" classid="clsid:eb6yhhh-f4db-480b-9c75-8d962790dfd34"></OBJECT>
```

I would like to know how can i call a javascript function from my C# usercontrol.

In V.B 6.0 there was a function which provided this functionality:

```
Hyperlink.NavigateTo("javascript:Test()")
```

But in C# i dont see any such function.

Comment: Ahh!  I get it now.  I'm going to delete my answer, and I suggest you change your question as this isn't really related to Lotus Notes.  You need to know how to call a javascript function from an object embedded in an HTML page.

Comment: Retagged to remove Lotus-Notes and Lotus-Domino

Answer (score 0):

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) should do it.

Try something like this:

```
if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("Test"))
{
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Test", "Test();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the below link:

[Catch events in javascript from .NET usercontrol](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/8e5823ca-bbea-4bfe-8826-8717ae16ba77)